# How to show X labels on marker view in Line Chart?

Tags: java, android, mpandroidchart

How to show the x-axis values in the line chart on the marker view.I have used the getVal() function to get the y-axis values but how to get the x-axis values on the marker view..Below is my code for the marker view.

```
    public class MymarkerView extends MarkerView
{
private TextView indices;

public MymarkerView(Context context, int layoutResource) {
    super(context, layoutResource);
    indices = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.indices);
}

// callbacks everytime the MarkerView is redrawn, can be used to update the
// content (user-interface)
@Override
public void refreshContent(Entry e, Highlight highlight) {

        indices.setText("Indices:" +e.getVal());
  }

@Override
public int getXOffset(float xpos) {
    // this will center the marker-view horizontally
    return -(getWidth() / 2);

}

@Override
public int getYOffset(float ypos) {
    // this will cause the marker-view to be above the selected value
    return -getHeight();
}
public void draw(Canvas canvas, float posx, float posy)
{
    // take offsets into consideration
    posx += getXOffset(posx);
    posy=0;
    // AVOID OFFSCREEN
    if(posx<65)
        posx=65;
    if(posx>350)
        posx=350;

    // translate to the correct position and draw
    canvas.translate(posx, posy);
    draw(canvas);
    canvas.translate(-posx, -posy);
  }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no direct method to get x value in MPAndroidChart 2.2.x
By sending the xvalues array to the `MarkerView` you can get it easily.
See the below `MarkerView` implementation.

```
public class MymarkerView extends MarkerView
{
    ArrayList<String> mXLabels;

    public MymarkerView(Context context, int layoutResource, ArrayList<String> xLabels) {
        super(context, layoutResource);
        mXLabels = xLabels;
    }

    @Override
    public void refreshContent(Entry e, Highlight highlight) {
        //get x value
        String xVal= mXLabels.get(e.getXIndex());
    }

    @Override
    public int getXOffset(float xpos) {
        // this will center the marker-view horizontally
        return -(getWidth() / 2);

    }

    @Override
    public int getYOffset(float ypos) {
        // this will cause the marker-view to be above the selected value
        return -getHeight();
    }
}
```

set the `MarkerView' to chart

```
ArrayList<String> xVals = new ArrayList<>();
//add labels to xVals
....
....

LineData lineData = new LineData(xVals, dataSets);

lineChart.setMarkerView(new MymarkerView(context, R.layout.custom_marker_view_layout, xVals);
lineChart.setData(lineData);
```

Or if you use **MPAndroidChart 3.0.0**, get the x value like this

```
@Override
    public void refreshContent(Entry e, Highlight highlight) {
        //get x value
       float xVal = e.getX();
    }
```

Comment: Thanks @Madhu ..it solved my issue with MPAndroidChart 2.4.4.

Comment: One more Question i wanted to ask ..I used the draw() method to position my marker view inside the chart .But in the above code i used a particular value of "posx" (65 and 350)to fix the position of markerview for my chart.This worked for the portrait view of my mobile screen .But  how to set the "posx" value to work for all the  android screen with a  fixed distance of marker view from left as well as right....What changes should i make to my posx value in "draw"  method.